# Doing payroll program using 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String employees[][]= {

            {"Anderson " ,  "Varejao",       "11.25",         "40"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Will" ,       "Cherry",       "12.25",          "35"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Lebron" ,      "James",        "60.25",         "56"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Kevin" ,      " Love",         "25.25",         "40"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Kyrie" ,       "Irving",       "14.25",         "42"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Dion" ,        "Waiters",      "6.25",          "40"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Tristan" ,     "Thompson",     "8.50",          "40"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Shawn",        "Marion",       "12.25",         "38"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"Joe",          "Harris",       "10.25",         "20"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {"James",        "Jones",        "10.25",         "25"  , null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        };
    bubbleSort(employees);


}


public static void bubbleSort(String t[][])
{

    for (int y=1;y<t.length-1;++y)
    {
        if (t[y][1].compareTo(t[y+1][1])>0)
        {
            String temp[]=t[y];
            t[y]=t[y+1];
            t[y+1]=temp;
            y=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Write a program which stores all the data for a payroll program in a 2 dimensional
array.
A. First Name
B. Last Name
C. Hourly Salary
D. Number of hours worked
When the user runs the program, have it calculate and store in the same 2D array
the following:
E. Gross pay
F. 20 % income tax deducted
G. Net pay
H. Total Hours Worked for all employees
I. Total Gross Pay for all employees
J. Total Net Pay for all employees
K. The name of the employee with the highest net pay (determined by the
program).

I am new with 2d arrays so please try to help me with this, i tried my best, i did as much as i could. Idk how i would do the strings from E-K?

Comment: "i tried my best, i did as much as i could"? Where? Can you show us what you tried? for each of E to K?>

Comment: The column headings and separators are formatting, not part of your data.  You should omit them from your array, and let your output method produce them at need.

Comment: Anyway, what are you stuck on?  I see you have methods aimed in the direction of computing some of the data for the extra columns.  Is your problem with converting between `String`s and numbers?  Is it with inserting the computed values into the arrays?

Comment: Your array contains column separators (`"|"`) and column headings (`"First Name"`, `"Last Name"`, etc.).  They are not actual data, and would be better omitted from the array.  You will ultimately have a method that produces formatted output of your result; it should be that method's job to produce column headers and separators on the output if you in fact want that.  They don't need to be in the array for that method to do so.

Comment: bubblesort doesn't need the outer loop over x..and y should start at 0

Comment: Yes.  Omit them, remove them, delete them, erase them, nuke them, eradicate them, trash them, wipe them [out], rub them [out], kick them [out], boot them [out], leave them out, and / or take them out.  Get rid of them.  Send them to the bit bucket.  Throw them in the bin.  Introduce them to file 13.  Clear now?

Comment: What do you mean "how would you assign hourlywage [... or ...] hours worked"?  They are in your data already!

Comment: I am not going to write your homework for you.  With that said, what are you hung up on?  Do you know the meaning of the terms?  Did you read (below) the answer I already wrote about performing the per-row computations?  What is the actual problem?

Comment: I'm sorry.  You seem to be having difficulties with the fundamentals of the (programming) language, and this is neither a suitable nor an appropriate venue for the kind of assistance you require.  Seek help from your instructor, or from some other knowlegeable person with whom you can discuss this face to face.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework dump, one that he is repeatedly dumping on us (see [repeat question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138512/doing-employee-data-using-2d-arrays)).

Comment: Monty, please refer to some [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on how to ask questions of this kind. In a word, just show what you tried, and then folks here will be more than happy to help unlock the problem.

Comment: @EricPlaton, can u see the code in the link i gave u and try to help me with what i can't do?

Answer (score 1):

your bubble sort should be more like:

```
public static void bubbleSort(String t[][])
{
 for (int y=0;y<t.length-1;++y)
 {
   // surname is col #2 as far as i can see
   if (t[y][1].compareTo(t[y+1][1])>0)
   {
     String temp[]=t[y];
     t[y]=t[y+1];
     t[y+1]=temp;
     y=0; // start from beginning
   }
 }
}
```

assuming all unnecessary date like header and column separators are removed

Comment: that's why i wrote **assuming all unnecessary date like header and column separators are removed**. Like @JohnBollinger already stated you should separate the data from the output format. If you bubble sort you have to restart the whole loop whenever you hit a pair that is in wrong order. You are done when there is no more such pair.

Comment: the swap of the elements ? that's not very expensive. you are only shuffling around references. In Java almost everything is a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `String` representations of numbers to values of numeric types via `Double.parseDouble()`, `Integer.parseInt()`, and similar methods of the other wrapper classes.  You can convert numeric values to `String`s by numerous means, among them the `String.valueOf()` methods.

I suggest you put `null` place holders into each row of your starting array for each column E-K.  Then iterate over the rows, for each one

1. parse the salary and hours to `double`s (`Double.parseDouble()`),
2. perform your various calculations,
3. convert each result to a `String` (`String.valueOf()`), and
4. store (a reference to) the resulting string in the correct field of the row.

Oncaphillis has already addressed details of the sorting requirement.